# Locally euclidean and first countability

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, alternative-proof, solution-verification, first-countable

Suppose $X$ is a topological space that is locally euclidean of dimension some $n \in \Bbb{N}$. Show that $X$ is first countable.

My attempt: Let $p\in X$ and $U$ a neighborhood of $p$. By assumption, there exists a neighborhood $U'$ of $p$ such that $U'$ is homeomorphic to a first countable space. Hence $U'$ is first countable.
Since $U\cap U' \subseteq U'$. It follows that $U \cap U'$ is first countable. Hence each $p \in U\cap U'$ has a local basis, $\mathbb{B}_p$. Since $U\cap U'$ is open in $U'$ and $U'$ is open in $X$, each term in $\mathbb{B}_p$ is open in $X$. Hence $\mathbb{B}_p$ the required local basis.

Is my attempt correct? What would be a better proof?

Comment: Wouldn't this follow immediately from the fact that neighborhood of p is homeomorphic to some open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: That implies that the neighborhood is first countable. Not every neighborhood is necessarily homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: Sorry, I confused the concepts!

Comment: Note that I assume the following definition of locally Euclidean of dimension $n$: every $p \in X$ has an open neighbourhood that is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost. You forgot to mention countability at a later point in the proof ("has a local basis" instead of "has a countable local basis"). You don't need to start with $U$, that only distracts.

Could again be more direct: let $p \in X$ and $U$ its locally Euclidean open neighbourhood, so there is a homeomorphism $h: U \to \Bbb R^n$. $\Bbb R^n$ is first countable and so $U$ is too. Hence $p$ has a countable local base $\Bbb B_p$ in $U$, but as $U$ is open, all members of this local base are open in $X$ too, and moreover form a local base at $p$ for $X$: if $O$ (open in $X$) contains $p$, there is a member $B \in \Bbb B_p$ with $B \subseteq O \cap U \subseteq O$ ($O \cap U$ is open in $U$ and we apply the fact that $\Bbb B_p$ is a local base for $U$). As $p$ is arbitrary, $X$ is first countable.

Comment: @topologicalmagician the homeomorphic fact follows immediately from your earlier proved fact about open continuous images: $U$ is the image of $\Bbb R^n$ under the continuous open $h^{-1}$ etc. But you didn't touch on it in your attempt, so I figured you knew that already.

Comment: yup! I'm trying to follow the advice you mentioned earlier.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where would the proof fail if I wanted to show that every locally Euclidean space is second countable? This statement doesn't seem to be true, but where would the above proof fail if I replaced first countable with second?

Comment: @topologicalmagician It would be false: let $X=\mathbb{R} \times D$ be the product of $\Bbb R$ with a discrete uncountable space. This is locally Euclidean but **not** second countable. BTW, connected counterexamples also exist: look up the long line.

Comment: @topologicalmagician An uncountable union of countable local bases need not be countable. The union of local bases always is a base, but the cardinality...